# ¿como implementar select2 en esta consulta con ajax?

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, select2

Buen dia

Tengo un ajax que me consulta una lista de maquinas que estas relacionadas con unos productos esto funciona perfectamente pero hay relaciones que tienen muchos registros y esto se hace tedioso al momento de buscar  investigando encontre *select2* al implementarlo en un select normal o sea con los datos escritos en los option dentro del html perfecto pero no he podido implementarlo en la consulta de ajax

**Blade**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="form-row">
        
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating">

                              <label class="control-label">Maquina</label>
                             <select class="form-control selector "  id="maquina" name="maquina" required>
                                 <option value=""></option>
                             </select>
                          </div>
                          </div>    
        
                          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                <label class="control-label">Producto/tamaño</label>
                                <select class="form-control slector " id="id_producto" name="id_producto" required>
                            
                                    
                                </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Estos son los dos select hay en class tengo "mi-selector" para el script de select2
**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // asignar los select a las variables 
    var plantSelect = $('#maquina');
    var areaSelect = $('#id_producto');
    // obteniendo las maquinas y llenando el select 
    function populatePlantSelect() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('getmaquinas') }}",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                $.each(response.data, function(key, value) {
                    plantSelect.append("" + value.nombre_maquina + "");
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Hubo un error obteniendo las maquinas!');
            }
        });
    }
    populatePlantSelect();
    // indica la maquina y lista los productos asignados a esa maquina 
    plantSelect.change(function() {
        var plantId = $(this).val();
        areaSelect.empty();
        if (plantId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('getproducto') }}",
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    maquina: plantId
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    areaSelect.append('') $.each(response.data, function(key, value) {
                        areaSelect.append("" + value.codigo + '__' + value.productos + "");
                    });
                    $('.mi-selector').select2();
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Hubo un error obteniendo los productos!');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    //despues de selecionar le producto asigna codigo de producto para llenar campo de la imagen y cargar 
});
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.mi-selector').select2();
    });
});
```

Se supone que con esto implementa la libreria *select 2*

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Dentro del `success` despues de tu iteracion pon la linea del select2  `$('.mi-selector').select2();`

Comment: gracias por tu comentario realize lo que me indicaste pero no funciona :/

---- success: function (response) {
     
                    $.each(response.data, function (key, value) {
                        plantSelect.append("<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.nombre_maquina + "</option>");
      
                    });
     $('.mi-selector').select2();
                }, ----

Comment: El problema es que los campos `<input class="form-control text-center mi-selector" ...>` son de tipo texto y `Select2`, por definición, es solo aplicable a `<select ..>`